# How to put eval string in function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My question is how can I put this

```
<%# Eval("about")%>
```

into this function

```
<% Utils.UserUtils.showNiceDesc(here goes string - "about") %>
```

In asp.net webforms?

Regards

Comment: `<%# Utils.UserUtils.showNiceDesc(Eval("about") %>` ?

Comment: Do you want to call the Eval("about") inside the method showNiceDesc ? Or want to pass the value of Eval("about") to the method?

Comment: this second, pass value of Eval("about") to the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want; it passes the result of Eval to a method.

```
<%# Utils.UserUtils.showNiceDesc(Eval("about")) %>
```

Comment: `<%# Utils.UserUtils.showNiceDesc(Eval("about").ToString()) %>` - this works perfect.

Comment: Sorry about the accidental down vote previously - edited your answer so I could undo it :P

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of `single` and `double` quotes.

```
'<% Utils.UserUtils.showNiceDesc(Eval("about")) %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like below
You should use `ToString()` function.

```
'<% Utils.UserUtils.showNiceDesc(Eval("about").ToString()) %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tag text='<%# Utils.UserUtils.showNiceDesc(((YourDataItemClass)Container.DataItem).about) %>' />
```

or

```
<tag text='<%# Utils.UserUtils.showNiceDesc(DataBinder.Eval("about")) %>' />
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx(v=vs.100).aspx